# Chrome and Firefox do not display image from database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, google-chrome, gridview, file-upload

Im having a problem to retrieve image from the database with Entity FrameWork 6 on Chrome and Firefox, I do not have that problem with Internet Explorer. It is the third "method" I have tried and both reach the same result.
It's is a simple web app that saves and retrieves image from database, the text and number columns is working fine, only image does not work.

SaveMethod

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Code for Save Image
if (FUImage.HasFile)
{
    int length = FUImage.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] img = new byte[length];
    FUImage.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(img, 0, length);
    ImageGallery ig = new ImageGallery
    {
        SLID = 0,
        ImageTitle = txtImageTitle.Text.Trim(),
        Picture = img
    };
    using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
    {
        dc.ImageGalleries.Add(ig);
        dc.SaveChanges();
        lblMsg.Text = "Successfully Saved";

        // populate Gallery image Here
        PopulateGallery();
    }
}
}
```

Select method

```
private void PopulateGallery()
{
// here code for populate image gallery
using (MyDatabaseEntities1 dc = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
{
    List<ImageGallery> imgGallery = new List<ImageGallery>();
    imgGallery = dc.ImageGalleries.ToList();
    gvGallery.DataSource = imgGallery;
    gvGallery.DataBind();
}
}
```

Convert method

```
protected string GetImageString64(byte[] Image)
{
// For convert byte image to base 64 string
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Image, 0, Image.Length);
return "data:image/png;base64 ," + base64String;
}
```

Template with Eval in GridView

```
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="100px" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Picture").ToString() == ""?"": GetImageString64((byte[])Eval("Picture")) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

The question is that the webapp is working perfeclty in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox and I cant find the anwaser anywhere, by the way, Im begginer with aspnet, and I ONLY need a site that saves and retrieves images, does not need to be with entity, so ANY solution or sugestion will be gratefull.

Thank for all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save only filename in database table and save image in your server path and called image from the server on your aspx page...

Comment: What he wants is to retrieve the image from (maybe BLOB) in database. Assume that is the right solution for for his web page, your suggestion does not add any value to a solution with his current implementation...

Comment: Pragnesh - By server path you mean "local drive/folder"? I saw something about that, but is it the right process? (I really do not know). I wonder if lots of image could "overload" the site and make it slow/heavy.

Comment: DTH - I am using a table with Image type column, but it works with Binary type as well

Comment: I could save the image in a local drive just like that
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + FileName));
But the question is IF it would solve the problem since only there's a problem with google chrome and firefox

Comment: Jeu Casulo - i used images to server/folder from begin but still i didnt get any Proble with chrom and firefox, Please check there is no issue with your image or project...Pleaes create an test website and try to load images...if it doesn;t show image thn there is prob with your system application,,If You dont mind then Paste your code and let me check your code